# What is the purpose of the "Views: views_view" component?

Tags: 7, features

Using the Features module, I notice there is a "Views: views_view" component, when creating a feature, but I don't see any setting for that component.

[image: screenshot]

I thought it would be list the views enabled in the site, but that doesn't happen, even if I have two views enabled.

What is the purpose of that component? Why isn't showing any settings?

I have tried with both the latest release candidate, and the lastest development snapshot, but the result doesn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the purpose of [the "Views: views_view"] component?

As you suspected, to allow views to be exported into a features module.

> Why isn't showing any settings?

I do not know. One possible explanation is, that all the enabled views are provided by other modules via an implementation of [hook_views_default_views()](http://views.doc.logrus.com/group__views__hooks.html#g23edb74860682fa88f75cf94b97c2e15). The Features module itself exports views by writing an implementation of [hook_views_default_views()](http://views.doc.logrus.com/group__views__hooks.html#g23edb74860682fa88f75cf94b97c2e15), so the Views module cannot distinguish between the two versions of the view. That's why the Features module does not allow views to be exported, that are provided by other modules.